# Allocation memory for Enumerable c#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I found this code in a library I am using:

```
public IEnumerable<BDDNode> Nodes {
    get {
        if (Low == null && High == null) {
            return new [] { this };
        } else {
            return new [] { this }.Union(Low.Nodes.Union(High.Nodes));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with Big models (ten thousands of nodes),
The code allocates Gigabytes of memory.

Do I have a way to change `new [] { this }` to anything else that will not create an object in every call of `Nodes` getter?

Comment: You can switch to `yield return`. That might or might not help depending on how `Nodes` is used

Comment: Do you really want to use `Union` or is `Concat` enough for your needs?

Comment: It should be without duplications. So I think it must be `Union`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping it all inside LinQ territory without additional materializing things looks better at a first glance:

```
private IEnumerable<BDDNode> ThisNodes {
    get {
       yield return this;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<BDDNode> Nodes {
    get {
        if (Low == null && High == null) {
            return this.ThisNodes;
        } else {
            return this.ThisNodes.Union(Low.Nodes.Union(High.Nodes));
        }
    }
}
```

**But** still not solves your problem that a `Union` will need to get all results in one place to perform it's function. [This is currently done with a Set](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,855) that sooner or later contains all (distinct) elements from both sequences. There is no way around that. If you want a union (meaning duplicate removal) you *have* to materialize your data. So maybe you are better served by `Concat`ing the sequences and worrying about duplicates later? Concatenating two sequences is purely LinQ deferred execution and involves no materialization of the results.

But that is a design decision that only you can make based on what your algorithm does.

Comment: I will check if I can perform `Distinct` after all the `get`s.

Comment: But as soon as you perform a `Distinct` you will have the same massive list of items in memory.

Comment: @DavidG But only *once*. Not once *for each node*. Although again, I have no idea if that's a viable solution for that algorithm.

Comment: Not sure what you means by that, why would it allocate for every node?

Comment: @DavidG It seems to me this is some kind of network or tree, with High and Low being of `IEnumerable<BDDNode>` as well, so this Union will be done *per Node* while it might be suficient to get all data and do the distinct once in the end. So there is only one big `Set` instead of one `Set` per node.